# How should I vote on a question which I consider too low quality to migrate?

Tags: support, migration, vote-to-close, low-quality

I came across [a question in the close queue](https://serverfault.com/review/close/242119), which I feel need to provide some more information in order to be a good question.

I could vote to close the question, but I can see that the question already has three votes for migration to stackoverflow. Based on my understanding of how close votes work, this means that if I vote for closing I am effectively voting in favor of migrating the question to stackoverflow - regardless of what reason I choose when voting to close.

How should I vote if I don't feel that question is suitable for migration to stackoverflow?

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" - determine whether that applies, then act accordingly.  (Since you mentioned low quality...)

Answer (score 11):

You should still vote to close. Other people's votes are not your responsibility. All you can do is vote correctly.

Certainly, disagreeing with a close vote isn't a valid reason to flag, for example.